# WHERE con LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas, "TARIFA" y "DETALLE"
En la tabla tarifa hay 2 registros

| id_tarifa | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TARIFA 1 |
| 2 | TARIFA 2 |

Luego la tabla "DETALLE" incluye los precios para los productos en las distintas tarifas, para resumir tengo

| ID_TARIFA_DETALLE | ID_TARIFA | ID_PRODUCTO | PRECIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 30 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 12 |

Bien, resulta que el producto con ID 1 tiene precio en las 2 tarifas, pero el producto con ID 2 no, ya que, imaginemos, la tarifa con ID 2 se creó a posteriori de la 1 por lo que el producto con ID 2, tenía precio en la tarifa con id 1 pero no en la tarifa con id 2.

Lo que quiero es hacer una consulta que por ID de producto o bien me saque los precios de las 2 tarifas si el producto las incluye o, en caso de no incluirla que salga NULL, por ejemplo

```
SELECT A.*,B.* 
FROM tabla_tarifa a left join tabla_tarifa_detalle b on (a.id_tarifa = b.id_tarifa) 
where b.id_product = 1
```

Esta consulta da como resultado, como no puede ser de otra forma, esta tabla

| id_tarifa | nombre | ID_TARIFA_DETALLE | ID_TARIFA | ID_PRODUCTO | PRECIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TARIFA 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 25 |
| 2 | TARIFA 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 30 |

Pero ahora quiero sacar las tarifas del producto con Id 2; evidentemente NO EXISTE para el producto con id2 un precio en la tarifa 2, pero aún así quiero que SALGA esa fila y como precio que apareciera NULL, como corresponde con la definición de LEFT JOIN (quiero todos las filas de la izquierda), pero no me hace caso. Si yo ejecuto esto

```
SELECT A.*,B.* 
FROM tabla_tarifa a left join tabla_tarifa_detalle b on (a.id_tarifa = b.id_tarifa) 
where b.id_product = 2
```

Aparece esto

| id_tarifa | nombre | ID_TARIFA_DETALLE | ID_TARIFA | ID_PRODUCTO | PRECIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TARIFA 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 12 |

Y lo que pretendo es que aparezca ESTO

| id_tarifa | nombre | ID_TARIFA_DETALLE | ID_TARIFA | ID_PRODUCTO | PRECIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TARIFA 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 12 |
| 2 | TARIFA 2 | Null | Null | Null | Null |

¿Hay alguna forma de conseguirlo?

¿QUÉ COSAS HE INTENTADO? y sin éxito :(

- Incluir en el where un "or b.id_product is Null"
- Hacer un FULL JOIN (con UNION)

Comment: si quieres que te aparezca el 1 y 2 de la tabla de la izquierda, quita el where, es el where que te está filtrando las filas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes poner la condición dentro del lef joint

```
SELECT a.*,b.* 
FROM tabla_tarifa a 
left join tabla_tarifa_detalle b on a.id_tarifa = b.id_tarifa and b.id_product  = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Nada chicos, conseguido, simplemente hay que usar "left outer join" y no usar "where" si no poner la condición dentro del "on", de ese modo consigo lo que quería.

Saludos!

Comment: según yo es solo quitando el where, el left join estaba bien

Comment: De hecho, `LEFT JOIN` es lo mismo que `LEFT OUTER JOIN` :) La palabra OUTER es _opcional_.